# Updating an array in SharePoint spfx using React & PnPJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-native, sharepoint

I'm creating a web app that allows the user to update their status and location.

I have a data list table on SharePoint with the user's name, email address, status (for example: online, offline, or busy), location (which is a select field), along with other fields.

The web app is just 2 different select fields. Which allows the user to update his status and location.

When the user accesses the page on `componentDidMount()` I'm getting the user's email addresses (since he's logged into SharePoint) and then filtering the data list array to view the element for his information (so looking for his email address in the `MyList`. The part I'm stuck at now is updating the `MyList` list with the selected response that the user selected.

Using PnP-JS i found this should be possible here are two links showing the `update()` function.
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Basic--Operations

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items

My code found here:

```
export default class SigninLocationWebpart extends React.Component<ISigninLocationWebpartProps, {Status: string, Location: string, userName: string, getEmail: string, selectedUser: any}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Status: 'Online',
            Location: 'New York',
            userName: '',
            getEmail: '',
            selectedUser: {},

        };

        this.handleChangeStatus = this.handleChangeStatus.bind(this); 
        this.handleChangeLocation = this.handleChangeLocation.bind(this);   

    }

    handleChangeStatus(event) {
        const { value } = event.target;
        this.setState({ Status: value });
    }

    handleChangeLocation(event) {
        const { value } = event.target;
        this.setState({ Location: value });
    }


    private _onUpdate(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();

        //This is where I need help on updating list
        let list = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList")

        //Instead of getting by ID i need to get by that selectUser array I believe
        list.items.getById(1).update({
            Status: this.state.Status, //User changing from Online to Offline
            Location: this.state.Location //User changing from New York to Los Angeles
        }).then(i => {
            console.log(i);
        });

    }       

    public componentDidMount() { 
        if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
        }
        else if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.SharePoint || Environment.type === EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {

            //This gets the current users info and sets it to username and email
            sp.web.currentUser.get().then((response : CurrentUser) => {
                //console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    userName: response["Title"],
                    getEmail: response["Email"],
                })
            })          


            //This gets the list of all all items in the list
            pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
                console.log(items);

                //Comparing email from sign in user and filtering items array to get that element
                var compareEmail = this.state.getEmail;
                console.log(compareEmail);

                let selectedUser =  _.filter(items, function(item) {
                    return item.Email_x0020_Address.toLowerCase() === compareEmail.toLowerCase();
                });
                console.log(selectedUser);


            });


        }
    }



    public render(): React.ReactElement<ISigninLocationWebpartProps> {
        return (

            <div className={ styles.signinLocationWebpart }>
                <h3>Hello {this.state.userName}</h3>

                <form onSubmit={this._onUpdate}>

                    <label>
                        Check In our Out
                    </label>
                    <select name="Status" value={this.state.Status} onChange={this.handleChangeStatus}> 
                        <option value="Online">Online</option>
                        <option value="Offline">Offline</option>
                        <option value="Busy">Busy</option>
                    </select>

                    <label>
                        Location
                    </label>
                    <select name="Location" value={this.state.Location} onChange={this.handleChangeLocation}> 
                        <option value="New York">New York</option>
                        <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

                </form>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of getting all items in the List, and then filtering for the current user, you should get only the item(s) for the current user to begin with.  Once you list gets large, you would be performing a lot of overhead by retrieving all items.

Secondly, and what you allude to in your comments, is that you need to specify the ID of the item to update.  So, in your `componentDidMount`, after you get the List Item for the current user, save that Item in your state.

```
public componentDidMount() { 
    if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
    }
    else if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.SharePoint || Environment.type === EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {

        //This gets the current users info and sets it to username and email
        sp.web.currentUser.get().then((response : CurrentUser) => {
            //console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                userName: response["Title"],
                getEmail: response["Email"],
            });

            pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.filter("Email_x0020_Address eq '" + this.state.getEmail + "'").top(1).get().then((items: any[]) => {
                if (items && items.length) {
                    this.setState( { selectedUser: items[0] } );
                }
            });
        })          

    }
}
```

Then at update time, you can use the ID of that item to save it.

```
private _onUpdate(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    //This is where I need help on updating list
    let list = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList")

    //Instead of getting by ID i need to get by that selectUser array I believe
    list.items.getById(this.state.selectedUser.ID).update({
        Status: this.state.Status, //User changing from Online to Offline
        Location: this.state.Location //User changing from New York to Los Angeles
    }).then(i => {
        console.log(i);
    });

}
```

Additionally, you'll want to make sure you are binding your submission handler just like you are doing for your onchange handlers in your constructor:

```
this._onUpdate = this._onUpdate.bind(this);
```

I will also add, that unless you've make sure to pre-populate the List with all possible users, and will always keep it updated with new users, it would be best in to put a check in your `_onUpdate` that if `this.state.selectedUser == null || this.state.selectedUser.ID == null` then you should create a new item (and add the new item to your `this.state.selectedUser`), instead of updating.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. This really helped me get a better understanding on how to properly approach this problem. On `pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.filter("tolower(Email_x0020_Address) eq '" + this.state.getEmail.toLowerCase() + "'").top(1).then((items: any[]) => {` I'm getting an Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Items' on the then() function

Comment: I think `then()` needs to be replaced with `forEach()` . But I think it's still causing issues maybe with the `top(1)` ?

Comment: No, sorry, I left out the `get()` before the `then`.  I updated the answer, see if that works better.

Comment: thank you. That fixed that issue but in the console it's giving me a `Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [400] 
    at new ProcessHttpClientResponseException` error

Comment: also before that I'm getting a GET error and it has this link here `https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/sites/lt/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$filter=tolower(Email_x0020_Address)%20eq%20%27joesmith@gmail.com%27&$top=1` when i go to that link it has this error `<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The query is not valid.</m:message>`

Comment: Try taking the tolower() off and just compare the email address directly.  The documentation says the OData filter supports it, but I see numerous posts from people saying it doesn't work.

Comment: hope you had a great weekend. I was working on this and I don't think it's supported even when removing the tolower() or changing the email in the database to be exactly capitalized like the user email it still doesn't seem to work. I wonder if it's because this only returns a true or false?

Comment: while `tolower()` may not work, this sort of thing is pretty much exactly what `filter()` was intended for.  Something to double check -- I have written this assuming that the **internal** name of your "Email Address" field was `Email_x0020_Address` -- double check that that is the case and potentially replace `Email_x0020_Address` in the filter with the actual internal name of your field.

Comment: If you want to try hard-coding an email address, make sure to use this format:  `....filter("Email_x0020_Address eq 'yourtest@email.com'")...` -- note that the entire filter string is enclosed in double quotes `" "`, but within that the email address you are testing is in single quotes `' '`.

Comment: So, I just validated in my dev tenant that `tolower` fails, despite what the documentation says -- However, I also validated that the ` eq ` comparison is not case-sensitive.  In my case, I successfully retrieved an item with a title of "Stock" with the `filter("Title eq 'stOCk'")`.  I have updated the code in my posted answer, but the short is to change your filter to `....filter("Email_x0020_Address eq '" + this.state.getEmail + "'")....`